Using a function to allocate complex custom data structures
I am trying to allocate memory for certain data structures (array, matrix, custom_array, ...). The problem I think I am facing is that I am not able to cast the proper types to the passed pointers which I initialized to NULL. Keep in mind that I am passing the adresses of the pointers
( init_structs(&ptr1, &ptr2, &ptr3, ...) ):
int init_structures(void* d_decharge,
                    void* d_poubelles,
                    void* e_camions,
                    int m, int n,
                    int *tamp_id, int* file_msg_id)
{
    *d_decharge = (int*)malloc(m * sizeof(int));
    if (*d_decharge == NULL){
        printf("echec malloc dist_decharge\n");
        return 1;
    }

    *d_poubelles = (int**)new_matrix(m);
    if(*d_poubelles == NULL){
        printf("echec malloc dist_decharge\n");
        return 1;
    }

    key_t key_tamp = ftok("./src/main.c", 64);
    int id = shmget(key_tamp, sizeof(camion_t) * n, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if (id == -1){
        printf("echec creation du tampon etats_camions, error[%s]\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    *tamp_id = id;
    *e_camions = (camion_t*)shmat(*tamp_id, NULL, 0);
    
    key_t key_msg = ftok("./src/main.c", 64);
    id = msgget(key_msg, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    if(id==-1){
        printf("echec creation de la file de messages Faffec, error[%s]\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    *file_msg_id = id;
    return 0;
}

I tried declaring the proper types but that just runs into a passed by copy problem.

You cannot deference a void pointer: *d_decharge.  d_decharge should be a int ** if you want the caller to get the malloc'd address.

OT: If you want to return a boolean true or false, use the actual bool type and return true or false. Which by the way you have mixed up, so you return "true" or failure and "false" on success.

@Someprogrammerdude I wish my issue revolved arround just that.

Standard sidenote: Should I cast the result of malloc (in C)?

When you exit early on a malloc failure, do you want to leave the successfully allocated memory, or clean it up?

@Chris, I had another function (destroy()) that was cleaning the structures I made so I would be called either on failure or at the end of the main(), but apparently that's still wrong since the allocated memory pointers only exist in the scope of the init() so that's also something to keep an eye out for.


The problem I think I am facing is that I am not able to cast the proper types to the passed pointers [...]. I am passing the adresses of the pointers
( init_structs(&ptr1, &ptr2, &ptr3, ...) ).

You could perform enough casting to make your function work, but why?  Most casting for other than arithmetic purposes is symptomatic of poor design.  In this case, you are passing (apparently) an int **, an int *** (yuck), and a camion_t ** to init_structures(), and relying on those types, but the function is receiving them as type void *.  To work with that, you would need to convert the pointers back to their original types inside the function, but it would be so much cleaner and easier then to just pass them as their original types:
int init_structures(int **d_decharge,
                    int ***d_poubelles,
                    camion_t **e_camions,
                    int m, int n,
                    int *tamp_id, int* file_msg_id) // ...

Of course, that assumes that those are in fact the correct types, as they sure should be.  But if the original ptr1, ptr2, and ptr3 are instead all void * then

WTH?
You would want to use type void ** for the function parameters instead of void * or the above pointer types.


void** runs into must modifiable lvalue error, been there done that, and yeah the yuckiest solution the best one apparently, I was always told to keep the pointers to a max of ** but apparently there are exceptions.

@MegrahYacine, yes, int *** parameters are nasty, but hiding them behind a different declared data type makes them more nasty, not less.  What you should be considering instead is a different underlying data type.  You seem to be describing d_poubelles as a pointer to a matrix, so the natural thing to do would be to have a structure type for the matrix.  Or even just a real 2D array, instead of an array of pointers.
